# Regarding visibility of lattice points

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

This question is related to visibility of lattice points from textbook Apostol Introduction to analytic number theory ( Chapter 3) .

Apostol defines Two lattice Points P and Q are called mutually visible if the line segment joining them contains no lattice points other than endpoints P and Q.

Then Apostol writes

> It is clear that (a, b) and (m, n) are mutually visible iff (a-m, b-n)  is visible from origin.

Can someone please tell how to prove this statement.

Comment: Translate the lattice by moving each points $(x,y)$ to $(x-m,y-n)$. Verify that this sends the lattice to itself, and that it sends straight lines to straight lines.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin  can you please give a more rigorous and formal proof ?

Comment: That is a rigorous argument

Comment: The non-rigorous argument is “just move your point of reference from the origin to $(m,n)$”; saying that you “translate the lattice by moving each point $(x,y)$ to $(x-m,y-n)$” *is* the rigorous way of saying that.